# A anotação de tipo em uma função não garante o tipo no Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, tipagem

É sabido que em Python não é necessário definir o tipo ao declarar uma variável e isso é interessante, porém, ao criar uma função, não posso restringir os tipos de atributos, então, ao fazer isso:

```
def x(a, b):
    return a + b
```

não consigo garantir q eu some dois números inteiros. Assim, isso acontece:

```
print(x('f', 'a'))
```

tenho como resultado `fa`, e não é isso que eu queria. Li na internet, que eu posso ditar o  tipo do atributo assim:

```
def x(a: int, b: int):
    return a + b
```

porém se faço isso:

```
print(x('f', 'a'))
```

tenho como resultado `fa` do mesmo jeito.
Para solucionar o problema, eu estava usando isso:

```
def x(a, b):
    if type(a) != int or type(b) != int:
        raise ValueError

    return a + b
```

Mas isso acaba ficando muito grande, além de ser gambiarra. Por fim, isso também acaba atrapalhando o polimorfismo. Como faço para corrigir isso?

Comment: O que exatamente você quer fazer? Se é garantir que os valores sejam inteiros, você já o fez. Linguagens de tipagem fraca são assim por definição e principalmente o Python, em que a filosofia principal é: o desenvolvedor sabe o que está fazendo, então se a função não deveria receber uma string, não deveria existir no código tal chamada.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss na verdade, isso é apenas uma resistência minha, que acostumei com o C++, porém, como fica o polimorfismo se eu não tiver as assinaturas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sim - esse é o comportamento esperado e desejado de uma função em Python.

As dicas de tipagem possíveis com a sintaxe `def x(a: int, b: int)->int:` - são apenas isso: dicas. Há alguns programas que verificam estáticamente isso é - antes de você executar o programa, se há "vazamento de tipos" - isso é, se algum ponto no sue programa chama essa função com algo que não seja um inteiro. O programa oficial para isso é o `mypy` - mas perceba que tanto o uso de um verificador de tipagem como o mypy quanto fazer alguma coisa depois que ele emitir seus avisos são completamente opcionais.

A prática correta mesmo é garantir - por meio de testes unitários e testes de integração - que suas funções façam o que você quer quando receberem os parâmetros corretos.

Como foi comentado na pergunra, Python é uma linguagem para "adultos que consentem com o que fazem" - então, se sua função foi criada, e está documentada assim, para trabalhar com inteiros e mesmo assim você  a chama com strings, você deve saber o que está fazendo.  (E para evitar que isso ocorra sem querer, é que existe a sintaxe de type-hinting e verificadores como o mypy).

O que acontece é que se você chamar a função com parâmetros realmetne incompatíveis, em algum ponto, será levantada ma exceção de `TypeError` no corpo da função (nesse caso, se você passar um número e uma string, por exemplo). Python sendo uma linguagem dinâmica, isso é causado em tempo de execução - por isso a importância de ter testes no seu programa.

Agora, em casos excepcionais - veja bem, não é para ser a regra - você pode sim colocar checadores de tipo em tempo de execução. Python permite mecanismos bem mais sofisticados do que o exemplo de `if type(a) == ...` que você colocou. Mas tudo o que essas verificações podem fazer em tempo de execução é ... levantar uma exceção. Uma exceção que acabaria acontecendo naturalmente quando o código tentar executar algo impossível com os parâmetros passados. Com pouquissímas exceções - como nesse caso: as strings são concatenadas. Mas de novo, se fossem dis parâmetros que não pudessem ser somados com o operador "+", faria pouca diferença para o programa em tempo de execução se o erro acontecesse logo na entrada da função, ou na linha de baixo, onde é feita a operação de soma.

Por outro lado, esse tipo de coisa definitivamente não é papel do compilador de uma linguagem dinâmica como Python. A linguagem, assim como PHP Javascript, Ruby, simplesmente não precisa reservar espaço de antemão quando compila o programa para um único tipo de parâmetro na função. Lignuagens como C, Java, G são estáticas - e o erro em tempo de compilação acotnece não para ser "bonzinho e achar possíveis falhas" - mas sim por que o parâmetro incompatível não se "encaixa" na chamada  a função, já em tempo de compilação. Entao, novamente, em Python há o passo opcional de verificação estática de tipagem com o mypy.

Agora, só para não encerrar a resposta sem nenhum exemplo concreto, vou dar um exemplo de como se poderia verificar os parâmetros de entrada e saída de uma função sem ser necessário codificar um `if` com uma expressão para cada parâmetro.

Uma abordagem possível é com o uso de um "decorator" - isso em Python é uma função que recebe uma outra função como parâmetro (a funçao que é "decorada"), e devolve uma terceira função - que via de regra é a função original "envelopada" em algum código complementar.  Há uma sintaxe especial para se aplicar decorators, o que torna seu uso bem prático.

Então, no caso, podemos combinar as typehints e criar um decorator que,
ao ser chamada a função, ele verifica se os parâmetros passados estão de acordo com os tipos especificados pelo type-hinting na função decorada. Em caso de parâmetros incompatíveis, o decorator levanta um TypeError, caso contrário procede com a chamada original.

A sintaxe do Python ermite uma grande flexibilidade em como os parâmetros são passados para uma função - e criar esse decorator para dar conta de todas as formas possíveis, dentre parâmetros com nome, parâmetros expandidos com "*" que levasse em conta todos as formas possíveis de passagem de parâmetro seria razoavelmente complexo - se for realmente usar algo assim, é melhor fazer uso das funções de utilidade existentes no módulo  `inspect` da biblioteca padrão. Um decorator que atue só sobre parâmetros passados por nome no entanto, pode ser bem simples. As type-hints ficam dentro do attributo `__annotations__` da função original:

```
def typecheck(func):
   annotations = func.__annotations__
   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
       if args:
            raise TypeError("Only named parameters allowed")
       for name, value in kwargs.items():
           if not name in annotations:
               raise TypeError(f"Parameter {name}  does not exist")
           if not isinstance(value, annotations[name]):
               raise TypeError(f"Parameter {name} must be an instance of {annotations[name].__name__}")
       # all parameter type parameters succesful - perform original function call:
       return func(**kwargs)
   return wrapper
```

E no prompt interativo:

```
In [16]: @typecheck
    ...: def soma(a: int, b: int):
    ...:     return a + b
    ...: 
In [17]: soma(a="f", b="a")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
(...)

TypeError: Parameter a must be an instance of <class 'int'>
```

**atualização**
O autor da pergunta continuou nos comentários:

> Ok, anotado, eu sei o que eu estou fazendo ao programar, mas, como
>   fica o polimorfismo? Eu aprendi que para diferenciar funções em uma
>   classe, o compilador verifica sua assinatura, ou seja, a quantidade de
>   parâmetros e seus tipos. Se eu não posso dizer ao compilador quais são
>   os tipos, como ele vai diferenciar duas funções com o mesmo nome e
>   mesma quantidade de atributos, mas com comportamentos diferentes?

Sendo uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica, o conceito clássico de "polimorfismo" não existe em Python - o que chegam como argumentos para qualquer função ou método são "objetos Python".

Na verdade,  não precisar re-escrever quase todos os métodos por conta de alterações triviais nos objetos passados como parâmetro uma vantagem. Por exemplo, qualquer função feita para realizar cálculos com operações básicas em tipos numéricos vai funcionar com inteiros, floats, complexos, frações, Decimais, etc... (e claro, você pode especificar que só quer o tipo `numbers.Number` no type-hinting para englobar todos os tipos numéricos, graças a mecanismos de "adoção de herança" vai funcionar bem - mas você não precisa limitar o seu método se isso não for necessário)

Se você precisa de comportamentos diferentes de acordo com a tipagem dos parâmetros que chegam, suas opções são as seguintes:

1. Usar um bloco `if/elif/else` para selecionar o comportamento desejado
2. Usar o decorador `functools.singledispatch` - ele permite, com o uso de decoradores, uma forma de polimorfismo em funções separadas baseado na tipagem do *primeiro* argumento passado para uma função - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch
3. Repensar o seu design - faz sentido você ter uma função com a mesma assinatura que faz coisas diferentes dependendo do tipo de dado?

   - por exemplo, se você está trabalhando com interfaces em classes, e quer que alguns métodos com o mesmo nome estejam disponíveis em várias classes diferentes, o primeiro parâmetro (self) sempre vai ser um objeto do próprio tipo da classe - e nesse caso, a implementação distinta já naturalmente acontece na própria classe. O polimorfismo só entraria pra distinguir o código do segundo parâmetro em diante.
4. Criar um conjunto de utilitários e padrões entre decoradores e tabelas em dicionários para ter ferramentas "pessoais" para polimorfismo em seus projetos. Isso é bem tranquilo e divertido dada a natureza da linguagem

Comment: Ok, anotado, eu sei o que eu estou fazendo ao programar, mas, como fica o polimorfismo? Eu aprendi que para diferenciar funções em uma classe, o compilador verifica sua assinatura, ou seja, a quantidade de parâmetros e seus tipos. Se eu não posso dizer ao compilador quais são os tipos, como ele vai diferenciar duas funções com o mesmo nome e mesma quantidade de atributos, mas com comportamentos diferentes?

Comment: @FelipeNascimento esse é um comportamento das linguagens de tipagem forte, apenas. Como no Python uma mesma variável pode receber um valor de diversos tipos, não faz sentido você definir múltiplas funções. Neste caso você implementa apenas uma função e define seu comportamento de acordo com os tipos passados por parâmetro ou cria múltiplas funções com nomes distintos.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss: a pergunta voltou a "subir", então um comentário - Python é uma linguagem de "tipagem forte". A característica que você se refere é "tipagem estática" (oposta a "tipagem dinâmica", que é o caso do  Python). Python tem tipagem forte e dinâmica.

Comment: @jsbueno Bem notado.