# receber um objeto em um metodo do mesmo tipo da classe do metodo

Tags: python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos, método, instanciar-objeto

estou passando um codigo java para python e me deparei com isso(cortanto umas partes)

```
public class TreeNode {
    public TreeNode(TreeNode pai) {
```

como faço para receber o pai do tipo TreeNode em python?

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, pai: TreeNode):
```

isso da "Unresolved reference 'TreeNode'
qual maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: O que seria exatamente "pai do tipo"? Você precisa referenciar a própria classe? Lembre-se que Python, diferente do Java, possui tipagem dinâmica, então não faz sentido você definir um tipo no argumento - e mesmo que o faça isso não interferirá na execução do código; será apenas uma **anotação** de tipo. Veja mais em [Python 3: Tipos de Atributos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220637/5878)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em python é preciso fazer o teste dentro do método/construtor, ex:

```
class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, pai):
    if not isinstance(pai, TreeNode):
      print('Nao Ok')
    else:
      print('Ok')
```