# Quantidades de jogos de um código de apostas e os seus números aleatórios em ordem crescente no Python

Tags: python

O código de sorteio de loteria produz 6 dezenas aleatórias e gostaria de saber **como deixar esses números em ordem crescente**, além de **definir a quantidade de jogos que o usuário quer que seja gerado**.

```
# Como que o código fosse
Quantos jogos deseja realizar: 3
--- Números sorteados ---
2 | 6 | 25 | 31 | 45 | 58
8 | 16 | 28 | 40 | 41 | 42
4 | 10 | 19 | 34 | 47 | 50
```

```
# Meu código que produz apenas um jogo sem nenhuma ordem das dezenas
import random
def loteria():
    jogo = list(range(1, 60))
    random.shuffle(jogo)
    print ("--- Número da sorte ---")
    print(" | ".join([str(i) for i in jogo[:6]]))
loteria()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode modificar sua função de sorteio para que ela seja capaz de sortear uma quantidade específica de jogos, retornado uma *array* bidimensional, veja só:

```
import random

def loteria( qtd ):
    jogos = []
    dezenas = list( range(1, 61) )
    for i in range( 0, qtd ):
        random.shuffle(dezenas)
        jogos.append( sorted(dezenas[:6]) )
    return jogos

print("------ Numeros sorteados ------")
for jogo in loteria( 10 ):  # Gerando Dez Jogos
    print("| {:02d} | {:02d} | {:02d} | {:02d} | {:02d} | {:02d} |".format(*jogo))
```

Possível saída:

```
------ Numeros sorteados ------
| 05 | 09 | 21 | 30 | 39 | 53 |
| 03 | 18 | 38 | 47 | 49 | 53 |
| 05 | 15 | 22 | 34 | 38 | 41 |
| 15 | 40 | 42 | 45 | 49 | 51 |
| 04 | 27 | 29 | 30 | 33 | 41 |
| 02 | 16 | 25 | 37 | 45 | 53 |
| 05 | 20 | 26 | 46 | 52 | 55 |
| 21 | 42 | 45 | 55 | 58 | 59 |
| 02 | 07 | 27 | 33 | 48 | 55 |
| 15 | 25 | 35 | 40 | 44 | 53 |
```

Veja funcionado no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/WOBFzY)

Comment: a variável `qtd` eu ainda não entendi porque ela está no código e por que `.format(*jogo)` nunca vi esse tipo de sintaxe no `.format´

Comment: `qtd` se trata da quantidade de jogos que a função `loteria()` vai gerar. O asterisco antes do identificador da array pode se melhor entendido nessa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

Uma alternativa prática para isso é utilizar funções que a biblioteca `random` já te disponibiliza:

```
from random import sample

def loteria() -> list:
    return sorted(sample(range(1, 61), 6))

print(loteria())  # [6, 13, 15, 25, 32, 60]
```

Vale notar que o correto é `range(1, 61)`, pois `range(1, 60)` gera a sequência [1, 59], não incluindo o número 60.

Para permitir que seja definido a quantidade de jogos, basta receber um parâmetro na função:

```
from random import sample
from typing import Iterator, List

def loteria(n: int) -> Iterator[List]:
    for _ in range(n):
        yield sorted(sample(range(1, 61), 6))
```

Mas isso não garante que será sorteado `n` sequências distintas. Uma forma simples de se fazer isso seria armazenar as sequências geradas e verificar se não é duplicada:

```
from random import sample
from typing import Iterator, List

def loteria(n: int) -> Iterator[List]:
    sequences = []
    while len(sequences) < n:
        sequence = sorted(sample(range(1, 61), 6))
        if sequence not in sequences:
            yield sequence
            sequences.append(sequence)
```

Você pode também trabalhar com conjuntos, `set`, que por definição não permitem valores duplicados, porém, para tal, precisará passar o retorno de `sorted`, que é uma lista, para um tipo *hashable*, como uma tupla, por exemplo.

Comment: Mano 4 linhas de código, coisa louca kkk, mas por que `def loteria() -> list:` por que essa seta, achei que ia dá erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Mas eu senti falta da quantidade de jogos que o usuário quer jogar, mas tudo bem eu dou um jeito de inserir isso no código

Comment: @AlexF. A seta define a anotação de tipo do retorno. Ao fazer `loteria() -> list` estou *afirmando* que a função `loteria` irá retornar uma lista. Pode ler sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220637/5878)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função `sorted` pra obter a versão ordenada de uma lista, que por padrão é crescente:

```
def loteria():
    jogo = list(range(1, 60))
    random.shuffle(jogo)
    print("--- Número da sorte ---")
    print(" | ".join([str(i) for i in sorted(jogo[:6])]))
```

Quanto a jogar diversas vezes, é questão de receber um `input` e transformá-lo em inteiro; em seguida, basta repetir a chamada à função `loteria` o número de vezes desejado:

```
# Perguntar quantidade de jogos
n_jogos = input('Quantos jogos?')

# Transformar string de resposta em inteiro
n_jogos = int(n_jogos)

# Jogar jogo tantas vezes quanto o número de jogos
for _ in range(n_jogos):
    loteria()
```

Comment: Exatamente onde eu insiro essas linhas no código?

Comment: @AlexF. Basta você ler o código da resposta e buscar entender o que foi feito e qual é a diferença para o seu código que entenderá.