# Por que lambdas não suportam anotação de tipo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, característica-linguagem

Sabemos que o Python, a partir da versão 3.6, possui suporte a anotação de tipos nas funções e variáveis, de acordo com as [PEP 526 -- Syntax for Variable Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) e [PEP 3107 -- Function Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107).

```py
def int2float(x: int) -> float:
    return float(x)

a: int = 2
b: float = int2float(a)
```

Porém, mesmo depois da implementação dessas PEPs os lambdas não possuem suporte à anotação de tipo.

```py
int2float = lambda x: int: float(x)
```

Entendo que neste caso quebraria a sintaxe e geraria redundância pois não seria possível definir se o lambda é apenas `lambda x: int`, retornando a classe `int`, ou se esse é a anotação de tipo. Porém, acredito que com a adição de parenteses, que atualmente não são suportados, resolveria o problema:

```py
int2float = lambda (x: int) -> float: float(x)
```

Pelo visto decidiram que isso seria inviável ou que não fizesse sentido (excetuando-se o fato da linguagem ser de tipagem dinâmica).

Por que optaram por não adicionar as anotações de tipo no lambda? Não viram necessidade ou não faz sentido um lambda ter a anotação de tipo?

Comment: Relacionada: [A anotação de tipo em uma função não garante o tipo no Python 3?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220637/5878)

Answer (score 2):

Bom, segundo a [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#lambda) realmente não há suporte de anotações de tipo para as funções lambda e o motivo pra isso é descrito na própria PEP (tradução livre minha):

> A sintaxe de uma função lambda poderia ter sido mudada para suportar anotações, sendo 
>   necessário adicionar parêntesis ao redor do parâmetro. Contudo foi [decidido](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2006-May/001613.html)
>   não fazer essas alterações porque:
>
> - Seria uma mudança incompatível
> - Lambdas são "castradas" de qualquer forma.
> - Um lambda sempre pode ser portado para uma função em si.

Por "castradas", imagino que disseram que são funções menos complexas do que uma função normal.

A justificativa que o Guido deu por email foi que para o lambda aceitar as anotações de tipo seriam necessários parêntesis a mais ao redor das anotações para que o interpretador não ficasse confuso com os `:` das anotações e os `:` que vem antes da função em si.

Contudo, ele termina o email com

> Fortunately this is at least one of those things that we can fix with
>   a purely syntactical source code transformation...

o que pode significar que, em algum momento futuro, essas funções pode também ganhar a anotação. (:

Atualmente, se você quiser fazer as anotações de tipo, ou você transforma sua função lambda em uma função comum ou você pode usar o módulo `Callable` pra fazer a anotação, como foi descrito [nessa questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224997/type-annotation-for-function-returning-a-lambda)

Comment: Por que seria uma mudança incompatível? Como assim "lambdas são neutras"? Uma função também não seria dada que a linguagem possui tipagem dinâmica? Mesmo assim adicionaram as anotações para as funções. Quanto ao lambda poder ser portado para uma função, por que isso serviria como justificativa?

Comment: a mudança seria incompatível pq teria que mudar a sintaxe do lambda. imagina que você tenha uma função `lambda x: x+ 1`, se você fosse inserir a anotação de tipo, o parser ficaria confuso por causa dos `:` que separariam as anotações de tipo da função em si

Comment: Mesmo deixando os parenteses (e anotações de tipo) opcionais?

Comment: editei a resposta porque apertei o enter antes de enviar hahaha desculpa.
enfim, as lambdas são neutras porque valem pra qualquer tipo. a mesma função que eu citei ali em cima funciona pra int e float, então decidiram que forçar essa tipagem não faria tanto sentido

Comment: por fim, essa ideia de neutralidade da função lambda justifica o terceiro ponto citado por eles. se você *realmente* quer deixar as anotações, que são opcionais, você pode transformar em uma função que o parser não vai ficar confuso. não sei se fui clara o suficiente, mas foi o que entendi da PEP e do email que eu citei ali do Guido

Comment: O que ainda está confuso é essa parte sobre a neutralidade; as funções também são neutras perante os tipos de entrada e mesmo assim optaram por adicionar as anotações de tipo nelas. Por que justificaria para um e não para outro?

Comment: pra ser honesta, acho que foi um erro de tradução meu. no post original do PEP, chamaram a função de "neutered" e eu li "neutral" (inclusive vou editar a resposta para não ficar nada errado).  neutered significa "castrado", ou "menos poderoso" que uma função normal, por ser uma função oculta. talvez por causa disso acharam que seria um esforço desnecessário manter as anotações agora. não sei te dizer em detalhes o que justificou a decisão, mas me parece que só não estavam a fim mesmo

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu complementei minha resposta com trechos do email do Guido. veja se de alguma forma fica mais claro pra você. (: não sei se consigo ajudar muito mais que isso hahaha

Comment: vale lembrar que na mudança para Python 3 o plano do Guido era extinguir completamente as lambdas  - foram alguns protestos que a mantiveram (felizmente). Pessoalmente, acho que para lambdas poder anotar o tipo de retorno seria mais útil do que os valroes de entrada  - em um lambda verdadeiramente anônimo (sem estar atribuido a uma variável), os valores de entrada em geral estão "perto" no código, ou na documentação do lugar para onde ele está sendo passado como parâmetro.