# O que são type hints (dicas de tipo) em Python?

Tags: python, tipagem

Eu encontrei o seguinte código, fiz uma breve pesquisa e descobri que isso se chama "type hint", mas não sei o que significa.

```
def dobro(n: int) -> int:
    return n * 2

print(dobro(3))
```

Comment: Veja aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220637/a-anota%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-tipo-em-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-n%c3%a3o-garante-o-tipo-no-python-3 - tem essa também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/362088/quais-ganhos-eu-tenho-em-especificar-o-tipo-do-argumento-de-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o

Comment: NÃO use imagens de código. Copie o texto do seu código, cole-o no corpo da pergunta, e depois formate-o como código. Isso ajuda outros a ler e testar seu código mais facilmente. [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: No geral todos detalhes estão em PEP484, PEP526, PEP544, PEP586, PEP589, PEP591, PEP612 e PEP613. Mas para ter uma ideia "resumida" pode ler o [**PEP 483 (The Theory of Type Hints)**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/)