# O que siginifica -> no python

Tags: python

Quando crio uma classe, o proprio TabNine já auto complementa colocando esse código:

```
def __init__ (self) -> None:
```

O que isso significa? Principalmente esse `-> None`

Comment: Como explicado no link indicado acima, é um type hint. Ver também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/362088/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/531499/112052

Comment: Muito Obrigado!