# O que significa -> em python?

Tags: python, operadores

Me deparei com um método do tipo, em python:

```py
def generate_foo_api_request_date() -> str:
    ...
```

Para que serve o ***"->"***? Isso significa que o metodo deve retornar uma string e caso nao retorne, quebra um erro?

Esse operador tem alguma coisa a ver com o ponteiro do C, por exemplo?

Comment: Isso se refere ao _type hint_. Veja aqui, pois talvez seja duplicada de : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/531499/o-que-s%c3%a3o-type-hints-dicas-de-tipo-em-python

Comment: E aqui [A anotação de tipo em uma função não garante o tipo no Python 3?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220637/a-anota%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-tipo-em-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-n%c3%a3o-garante-o-tipo-no-python-3)